# Value of a data property is not displayed in a loop in vue v-for

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I have this code that displays dates as the header of the table and bases the month on the selected month.

```
<tr>
    <th class="ui-table-header-cell center"  v-for="item in 31" :key="item.id">{{this.thisMonth}} month{{ item }}day</th>
</tr>
```

My `this.thisMonth` has already a value of `07` but will not be displayed in the header. And when I `console.log(this.thisMonth)` outside the loop, it displays. Can you help me out why is this not working. Apologies, I'm just new to this one.

Comment: In the template you do not need `this` . Just display the data property using `thisMonth`

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Thanks for that :) That does the trick.